# How to compress only files without their parent directory?

Tags: linux, mac, zip

I'm trying to compress files in a directory. Let's assume the directory is "test".

when I execute the following command and unzip the file, I get "test" folder and files inside the test folder.

**zip aa.zip test/***

How do I make it so that I get only files without "test" folder when I unzip the compress file?

Answer (score 4):

This command will work:

```
cd test; zip ../aa.zip *
```

If you need to do this for multiple directories, do this command for each one. `zip` will append the new files to the `aa.zip` archive.